# Creating a grid picture in R

Tags: r, graph, grid

I would like to create a 10x10 grid picture (I don't know the best thing to call it) that looks at a value in a df and colours the relevant grid based on the value in the df.

For example, I have a df as below (I have used a 5x5 as the example for simplicity):

```
column <- c(rep(c(1),5),rep(c(2),5),rep(c(3),5),rep(c(4),5),rep(c(5),5))
row <- rep(1:5, 5)
ID <- c(11:15, 21:25, 31:35, 41:45, 51:55)
class <- c(0,0,1,2,1,2,2,3,0,1,2,3,1,2,0,1,0,0,2,3,3,2,2,2,1)
df <- data.frame(column, row, ID, class)
```

I would like to create a grid that colours each point based on the `class` variable.
For example, for column 1 row 1 (`ID = 11`) the class is `0`. In the grid picture it would be coloured blue. Anything in class `1` would be coloured green, class `2` would be red and class `3` would be yellow.

It would look something like this:
[image]

Please excuse the simplicity of the example.

I am able to save the df as a .csv and run a macro based workbook in Excel to get the desired output, but I would like to be able to do it in R to keep everything all in one place.

Comment: That's a heatmap.  So something like `df %>% ggplot2(aes(x=column, y=row, fill=class)) %>% geom_tile()`.  Untested code.

Comment: You probably want a discrete scale instead: `ggplot(df, aes(y = row, x = column, fill = factor(class))) + geom_tile()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a heatmap. You can make it like this in ggplot2:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(column, row, fill = as.factor(class))) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "green", "red", "yellow"),
                    labels = 0:3, name = "class")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you!
Heatmap! Of course! Sometimes it's the simplest things one forgets. 

This has worked perfectly. Thanks again.